# Temporary failure in Name Resolution PHP-Ubuntu

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, aws

I keep getting this error very frequent:

```
Severity: Warning --> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This issue gets resolved only after Server restart. Considering this happens over a live server having millions of requests daily, restarting isn't a best option.

**[EDITED]**
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and connecting to an Aurora Cluster on AWS and the backend code resides on EC2

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here to provide any useful suggestions beyond generic tips that can be found on the first page of Google. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the version of Ubuntu you're using (2) the hostname that you're using to connect to MySQL

Comment: updated @matigo

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration the following details:

1. millions of requests daily
2. Aurora Cluster on AWS

You may want to take a look at your system to make sure you're not exceeding the [DNS quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-limits) for your account.

One of the stand-out items from the quota documentation is this:

> Each Amazon EC2 instance limits the number of packets that can be sent to the Amazon-provided DNS server to ***a maximum of 1024 packets per second*** per network interface. This quota cannot be increased. The number of DNS queries per second supported by the Amazon-provided DNS server varies by the type of query, the size of response, and the protocol in use. For more information and recommendations for a scalable DNS architecture, see the Hybrid Cloud DNS Solutions for Amazon VPC whitepaper.
>
> If you reach the quota, the Amazon Route 53 Resolver rejects traffic [...]

<sup>**Note:** Emphasis mine.</sup>

The "maximum of 1024 packets per second" bit is important because the *actual* number of packets per query can vary and there are typically multiple packets per DNS query.

If your server(s) are receiving millions of requests per day, then there is a high possibility that your server(s) are hitting that packet maximum:

- 1,000,000 requests / 86,400 seconds = 11.574 Requests per second
- 11.574 * 4 Packets¹ = 46-ish packets per second
- 1024 / 46 = 22.26-ish DNS calls per second

I cannot say this is definitely the problem, but this is a good place to start looking, particularly if your web servers have regular rush periods where traffic is not operating at a nice, flat average.

---

¹ Having been bitten by this problem in the past, I've measured that many DNS requests require an average of 4 packets per call

Comment: Thanks for your response. This I'm aware of, If I'm hitting the max requests per second, how do i resolve it? Usually restarting the server resolves it. What are the workarounds to avoid that limit?

Comment: I’ve not found a good, HA-friendly way to resolve the issue. I’ve done things like hybrid DNS and whatnot but, if the cluster fails over, a local DNS can result in connection failures for several seconds/minutes until the local TTL expires … which isn’t great. Generally I’ve had to go into the application code and look for SQL queries that are being needlessly duplicated or are unnecessarily myopic.

Comment: would using nscd services or dnsmasq help in not hitting the limit? since they would cache the NS queries for some time?

Comment: Yes, so long as the cluster never has to fail over to another instance. Otherwise you’re still waiting for the local TTL 

Comment: I tried to debug this using an AWS article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-find-cause-of-failed-dns-queries/ 
The most number of packets per second i could find was 26. But when i actually faced that php error today again, the packet count was less than 15 during that time frame.

Comment: I've run into similar problems, and blogged about my solution here: https://manuel.kiessling.net/2022/01/27/getting-rid-of-temporary-failures-in-name-resolution-on-aws-ec2/